# How can I add a "You Tied" message when variable is equal to player?

Tags: python

How can I add a "you tied, try again" message in my rock paper scissors game?

```
import random
name = input("Enter your name: ")
print ("Hello " + name + "!")

challenge = input ("I challenge you to a Rock, Paper, Scissors battle " + name + "!" + " Would you like to play? ")
if challenge != "yes":
    print ("Please type rock, paper, or scissors. Good Luck!")

choices = ("rock", "paper", "scissors")

Python = random.choice(choices)

player = input ("rock, paper, or scissors? ")
print("Python: ",Python)
```

Comment: You are a long way short of having a working game yet. Worry about the "tie" outcome as part of determining who actually wins. There are a few "rock, paper, scissors" questions already on stackoverflow if you care to search.

Answer (score 0):

```
if Python == player:
    print("You tied!")
```